# Cauchy+pointwise convergence $\Rightarrow$ uniform converges (for an operator in a Hilbert space)

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that the sequence of operators in a Hilbert space $H$, $\left(T_{n}\right)_{n}$,
is Cauchy (with respect to the operator norm) and that there is an
operator $L$, such that $Lx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}T_{n}x$, for
all $x\in H$ (i.e. the $T_{n}$ converge pointwise to $L$).

How
can I prove then, that $\left(T_{n}\right)_{n}$ converges with respect
to the operator norm to $L$ (i.e. $\left(T_{n}\right)_{n}$ converges
uniformly to $L$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$; there is $N=N(\varepsilon)$ such that if $m,n\geq N(\varepsilon)$, $\lVert T_n-T_m\rVert_{B(H)}\leq \varepsilon$. In particular, for all $n\geq N$ and all $x\in H$, we have 
$$\forall m\geq N,\lVert T_nx-T_mx\rVert\leq \varepsilon\lVert x\rVert.$$
Take the limit $m\to +\infty$ to get 
$$\forall n\geq N,\forall x\in H,\lVert T_nx-Lx\rVert\leq \varepsilon\lVert x\rVert.$$
We get $\lVert T_n-L\rVert_{B(H)}\leq \varepsilon$. The fact that $L$ is continuous can be seen by taking the particular value of $\varepsilon:=1$.

Comment: But why do we need the fact that $L$ is continuous ? (Or have you just stated that, because it is a nice corollary?)

Comment: I just stated that, since in fact what we show here is that the space of bounded linear operator endowed with the canonical norm is complete.

Answer (score 2):

The space of bounded linear operators under the operator norm is complete.  Hence, since $\{T_n\}$ is Cauchy, there exists an operator $T$ such that $T_n \to T$ in operator norm.  In particular, $T_n \to T$ pointwise, since $\|T_n x - T x\| \le \|T_n -T\| \|x\|$.  But $T_n \to L$ pointwise also, so we must have $T=L$.